# If $U$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$, Is it possible that $\alpha~v_3 + \beta ~v_4 ~\in~U$ for some $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb R $?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a vector space and $U$ is a sub-space of $V$. Suppose $v_3,v_4 \not \in U$.

(i). Is it possible that $\alpha~v_3 + \beta ~v_4 ~\in~U$  for some $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb R $?

(ii) Is there a specific condition when (i) is always true.

(iii) Suppose $u \in U$. Is it possible to express $u = \gamma~v_3 + \psi~v_4$ for some $\gamma,\psi \in \mathbb R?$

**Attempt:**

(i) if $\mathbb V - U$ is not a subspace, this condition might be possible.Suppose $U = \{(x, ~y,~z,0)~|~x,y,z \in \mathbb R\}$. Then $(0,~0,~0,~-1)$ and $(0~,0~,0~,1)$ both do not belong to $U$ but their sum does.

(ii) and (iii) I am not able to think of a rigorous approach to this. Could someone give a direction to think.

Thanka a lot for your help

Comment: Since $U$ is a sub-space of $V$, both contain the same zero element, i.e. (i) is true if $\alpha = 0$ and $\beta=0$. Are you excluding that case?

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas yes, excluding that case

Comment: How about constructions like; let $u_1,u_2\in U$ and $v_1\in V/U$, define $v_3 = u_1 + \beta v_1$ and $v_4 =u_2 - \alpha v_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) Yes, it is possible. Just take $\alpha=\beta=0$.

(ii) Yes: $\alpha=\beta=0$.

(iii) No. The vectors of the form $\gamma v_3+\psi v_4$ belong to the plane generated by $v_3$ and $v_4$. So, if $u$ doesn't belong to that plane, you cannot do that.

Comment: Is there a possibility though that $u \in U$ could belong to the generated by $v_3$ and $v_4$?

Comment: I am sorry , I meant : Is there a possibility though that $u \in U$ could belong to the plane generated by $v_3$ and $v_4$?

Comment: Yes, sometimes  that happens.

Comment: Not only sometimes, you can always find a pair $v_3, v_4$ which contains $u$, as per the construction I gave above. If $v_3$ and $v_4$ are given and you can not choose them, yes, it depends. You can write the exact condition on $v_3$ and $v_4$ using the basis vectors but it is ugly.